# How can I replace Canvas element with SVG?

Tags: c#, svg, canvas, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm currently trying to give a canvas element a shape that has a round border. As I know from my experience, the `CornerRadius` parameter/method does not exist in the `Canvas` class?

I want to use an SVG element instead of this white canvas element.

```
<Canvas Background="White" Width="250" Height="200">
    <TextBlock Text="LOW" Foreground="Black" FontSize="30" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="10"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock FontSize="40" Padding="0, 0, 300, 0" Margin="74" Text="11" Foreground="Black"></TextBlock>
</Canvas>
```

[image: This Canvas Element To SVG]

Answer (score 0):

### Problem Solved

```
<Border CornerRadius="10" Background="White" Height="200" Width="200">
                <Canvas Background="White"  Width="250" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                    <TextBlock Text="LOW" Foreground="Black" FontSize="30" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="10"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="40" Padding="0, 0, 300, 0" Margin="74" Text="11" Foreground="Black">
                    </TextBlock>
                </Canvas>
</Border>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).